# lxml and xsl document() function - continued

Tags: xml, xslt

I am facing exact same issue as described in this ticket:
[LXML and XSL document() Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831941/lxml-and-xsl-document-function)

I need to merge a.xml and b.xml (both local uris) using an xls file but I keep getting this error when using document function to load document b into the processing of doc a: 
lxml.etree.XSLTApplyError: Cannot resolve URI string://**STRING__XSLT**/b.xml

I have tried to add a resolver as suggested in the original answers, but it's not working - and documentation of resolvers on the lxml website is not very clear or detailed. Could anyone please elaborate on how I can use resolvers (or other methods) to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

//Nevermind - have located the error in my reference to parser in XSLT :)