# Importing xslt files of unknown name into master xslt file

Tags: python, xslt, permissions, temporary-files, add-on

What I am trying, and failing, to do is import a list of xslt files into another xslt file without me knowing the names of the files to import until the programme is actually run.

**Background**:
I am writing an extension mechanism for someone else's (python) project. The project uses an xslt script to transform an xml document into html. I have created a directory called "extensions" within the project and I want users to be able to put arbitrary sub-directories within this extensions directory. Each sub-directory represents an extension and will have a number of different files including, potentially, an xslt file.

I have a script that scans all sub-directories for xslt files and then writes out a new xslt file ('combined.xsl') with a series of  tags referencing all the xslt files that it found. I then import 'combined.xsl' into the project's main xslt file.

My first problem was that the project is generally going to be installed in an administrator's directory (eg. /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ or similar) but called by ordinary users. This means that when the script tries to create 'combined.xsl' it cannot be written due to insufficient permissions.

My next thought was to make 'combined.xsl' a temporary file (using the tempfile module), but then I cannot reference it from the project's master xslt file because tempfiles are created in different locations on different systems.

Is there a way to make either of these approaches work, or is there some completely different approach that I'm missing. I feel like this must be an uncommon sort of problem, but it's a little too abstract for google to be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually figured out an entirely different way of solving the problem that didn't involve writing to a file. However if anyone is dealing with a similar problem the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831941/lxml-and-xsl-document-function) is worth a look.